# RegEx - Extracting Characters Between Specific Phrase

Tags: regex, sas

I need to extract just the measure units from blood test text I've got, i.e.. "K/UL","M/UL","%",etc. at the following text:

```
WBC                            4.27-11.40 k/uL                        3.64 (L)
RBC                            3.90-5.03 m/uL                         4.30
Hemoglobin                     10.6-13.4 g/dL                         13.0
Hematocrit                     32.2-39.8 %                            36.1
MCV                            74.4-87.6 fL                           84.0
MCH                            24.8-29.5 pG                           30.2 (H)
MCHC                           31.8-34.9 g/dL                         36.0 (H)
RDW-CV                         12.2-14.4 %                            13.2
Platelet Count                 150-400 k/uL                           175
MPV                            9.2-11.4 fL                            8.6 (L)
Neut%                          28.6-74.5 %                            43.1
Abs Neut (ANC)                 1.63-7.87 k/uL                         1.57 (L)
Lymph%                         15.5-57.8 %                            43.7
Abs Lymph                      0.97-4.28 k/uL                         1.59
Mono%                          4.2-12.3 %                             9.3
Abs Mono                       0.19-0.85 k/uL                         0.34
Eosin%                         0.0-4.7 %                              3.6
Abs Eosin                      0.00-0.52 k/uL                         0.13
Baso%                          0.0-0.7 %                              0.3
Abs Baso                       0.00-0.06 k/uL                         0.01
```

Which means I need to recognize '-'+number+' '+**Unit to Extract**

I tried to use Negative look behind expression `(?<!-[0-9]?!([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+ )(\D)+` , which means to match only non digits if there is a '-' char followed with a float number, but it yields zero matches.

Please note that I'm using SAS (i.e. Perl RegEx).

Comment: Try `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\s*\K[^\s\d]+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mNZRsQ/1)).

Comment: Could [this](https://regex101.com/r/8MdBVR/1) help?

Comment: This does it: `\d\s(.*?)(?:(?:\s|$))`, see https://regex101.com/r/npJwCl/1

Comment: `\d+(?:\.\d+)?+(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)?+)?\s*\K\D*[^\d\s]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mNZRsQ/2))? `\w+/\w+|%` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mNZRsQ/3))?

Comment: Is the original blood test results text in a single row in a single variable ?

Comment: Use `\d-\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*\K[^\d\s]+`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mNZRsQ/4). If it works, please let know via a comment.

Comment: Please note that I'm using SAS, so using \K operator is not applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\d+-\d[\d.]*\s*\K\S+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/2u0cpP/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\d.]*                   any character of: digits (0-9), '.' (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       match reset operator
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
```

Comment: Can it be that SAS doesn't support '\K' operator ?

Comment: @ShakedNave From what I know, SAS uses PCRE that has support for `\K`.